# Convert INSERT IGNORE to Postgres INSERT

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'm currently working on a regex to transform sql syntax on Postgres syntax. I'm using geany to make replace text. For now, the syntax I try to change is this one :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO item_question_ (question_fk_,item_fk_) VALUES(1002,162);
```

Into :

```
INSERT INTO item_question_ (question_fk_,item_fk_) VALUES (1002,151) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM item_questionnaire_ WHERE question_fk_=1002 AND item_fk_ = 151)
```

I'm close but definitely not enought. I have this regex :

```
(INSERT IGNORE INTO (.*)_ (.*) VALUES(.*);) //Find information
INSERT INTO \2_ \3 VALUES \4 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM \2_ WHERE )// Transform information
```

The fact is that I'm missing the most important part : the `WHERE` clause.

How can I get the value `question_fk_,item_fk_` and `1002,151` to build my where clause ?

Additionnal note : Postgres version is under 9.5. I can't use `ON CONFLICT IGNORE`

Comment: Why use regex here? This is not appropriate tool for such transpiling task.

Comment: I need to make a massive translate, not a single line. Regex sems the more appropriate way to do it for me. BUt Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Why don't you upgrade to 9.5 and use `on conflict ignore`?

Comment: I don't have any control of the postgres version. I can't do the upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, just use `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` from Postgres 9.5+. But since you say that DB version is less than 9.5, this is your regex solution for this task:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO (.*) \((.*),(.*)\) VALUES \((.*),(.*)\); // capture

INSERT INTO \1 (\2, \3) VALUES (\4, \5) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM \1 WHERE \2 = \4 AND \3 = \5) // replace
```

But keep in mind that this regex will work only for inserting exactly 2 items.

Comment: It will do the job, there is only 2 item on my query. For my informations, is there an easy to extend this regex to work for more than 2 items ?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. As I said, regex is not good at that transformations. This query is higher-order language, that cannot be consumed by regular grammar. This calls for context-free grammar.

Comment: What could be a better to translate all request of a file than regex ?

Comment: Well, you could implement simplified parser based on SQL context-free grammar and do proper compilation (transpilation?) of one dialect to another. Or maybe a proper tool exists for this task already?...

Answer (score 5):

PostgreSQL 9.5+: Replace `IGNORE` in the original query with [`ON CONFLICT IGNORE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT), which is the PostgreSQL syntax for ignoring an update if any of the constraints fail.

Comment: The fact is tmy customer database is not on 9.5 version

Comment: @Pierre-AlexandreMoller Then put that information in your question.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of your query add `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`

Answer (score -2):

Use a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO item_question_ (question_fk_, item_fk_) 
    SELECT q, i
    FROM (SELECT 1002 as q, 151 as i) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM item_questionnaire_ iq
                      WHERE iq.question_fk_= t.q AND iq.item_fk_ = t.i
                     );
```

This also allows you to input the values only once.

Note:  I notice that the tables being referenced are *different*.  I assume this is intentional, but I was expecting the problem to be a unique constraint violation.

Also note that since Postgres 9.5, the better way to do this uses `ON CONFLICT IGNORE`, but your question is specifically about using `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: I'll still have to find a way to split the values parameters and the name of the column

Comment: @Pierre-AlexandreMoller . . . The question that I see is "Convert INSERT IGNORE to Postgres INSERT".